# Code required to make column not nullable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have a table where I mistakenly allowed NULL values in a column:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (
    EXAMPLE_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    FOO_ID INT,
    CREATED_ON DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- Oops!
    CODE VARCHAR(50),
    QUOTE DECIMAL(18,2),
    BAR_ID TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

    CONSTRAINT EXAMPLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (EXAMPLE_ID),

    CONSTRAINT EXAMPLE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (FOO_ID)
    REFERENCES FOO (FOO_ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,

    CONSTRAINT EXAMPLE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (BAR_ID)
    REFERENCES BAR (BAR_ID)
);

CREATE INDEX EXAMPLE_IDX1 ON EXAMPLE (FOO_ID);
CREATE INDEX EXAMPLE_IDX2 ON EXAMPLE (BAR_ID);
```

It's a fairly unimportant column (not indexed, not foreign key, not used in triggers...) and this is how I'd normally fix it:

```
ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE
ALTER COLUMN CREATED_ON DATETIME NOT NULL;
-- Runs in 1 second
```

However, I decided to use a GUI tool (SQL Server Management Studio, but all other tools I've tried do a similar thing) and found the whole process took like 20 minutes. The reason? The automatically generated change code is a 3351-line script that apparently tries to edit every single table on database that has a foreign key pointing to `EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE_ID`!

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SOME_OTHER_TABLE
DROP CONSTRAINT SOME_OTHER_TABLE_FK
GO


BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SOME_OTHER_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT
    SOME_OTHER_TABLE_FK FOREIGN KEY
    (
        EXAMPLE_ID
    ) REFERENCES dbo.EXAMPLE
    (
        EXAMPLE_ID
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION
    ON DELETE  CASCADE

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SOME_OTHER_TABLE SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Further digging reveals that the script creates a new `Tmp_EXAMPLE` table with the final definition and copies all data from `EXAMPLE`.

Is this complex process necessary? What's the exact problem with plain `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Can't imagine anything going wrong with `alter table`.  Curious why SSMS thinks it has to alter all the other tables, when the referenced column is not changing!

Comment: @Andomar - That's a side effect of dropping the original table and moving data to a new one. Yet I wonder why it does so in the first place.

Comment: Looks like [SSMS is programmed to re-create tables to change a column's nullability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802429/prevent-saving-changes-that-require-the-table-to-be-re-created-negative-effect)  Perhaps they have a list of safe operations, and altering the nullability of a non-PK was not on it?

Comment: @Andomar - Thanks for the link, that thread gives a pretty good hypothesis about why it does it that way. I guess the only question left is: is raw `ALTER TABLE` safe enough for this particular usage?

Comment: Sure, `alter` is very safe, not sure why you'd doubt that

Answer (score 1):

Just take care of current `NULL` values by updating them to a default value.
Then do your `ALTER TABLE`

#### Example for an integer

```
UPDATE [MyTable]
SET [MyColumn] = 0
WHERE [MyColumn] IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyColumn] INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

#### Example for a varchar

```
UPDATE [MyTable]
SET [MyColumn] = ''
WHERE [MyColumn] IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyColumn] VARCHAR(max) NOT NULL;
```

[Altering a column: null to not null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689766/3635715)

### Security Measure

Before, make sure you backup your database in case of you screw it all

### To make short

This whole complex scenario made by SSMS is not necessary there is no problem doing a plain `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was down voted, however this answer works and is the most straight forward solution.  Except for huge tables, where you may want to progressively update NULLs in batches.